# Erase the highlight JavaScript getSelection function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

highlight is not a problem. my problem is, on how can i erase the highlight using window.getSelection() in javascript. and create a node new span closing and new span opening to erase the selected highlight areas. See the screenShots.

```
function removeHighlight(sel) {

        if(sel.anchorNode.parentNode.className == 'hlt') {
            var replacementText = sel.toString();
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
        } 
    }
```

so far that is my function but createTextNode() can't read htmlEntities.

Comment: Please share code example.

Comment: put your code please

Comment: what do you want to acomplish ?
you want to select specific range and javascript should automatically erase that selected range ?

Comment: `document.getSelection().deleteFromDocument()`, maybe? I don't know what kind of browser support you're looking for.

Comment: no, if the user will highlight the highlighted text. let say i have a toggle highlight and erase. then i choose erase the highlighted text it will move out on the span with background yellow.

Comment: @Arif it will not erase or deleted but it move out to the span html element with background yellow. Really i have no idea on how to do that's why i can't write my code

Comment: please see the image above

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejos i can try to help but i cant get your idea clearly

Comment: You tried this? , http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:2006604?p=preview

Comment: @Arif Okay Sir Arif I explain. There are two toggle the "erase" and "highlight". if i choose highlight, all the text that i will highlighted will be encrypted a span element with class of hlt. then if i choose erase toogle all the highlighted text will be move out from the span. see the image above. my real problem is the erase. on i can move out from span element with the class of hlt.

Comment: Do you want remove all text highlighted while on a click ?
$('.hlt').remove();

Comment: @Rejs Sir it will move outside the span elements after mouseup. See the image above. thanks

Comment: does the highlighted text gets a special tag with a certain tag?

Comment: yes. once the text is highlighted. i will put them a span html element with its class named hlt. hlt value in the css is "background: yellow;"

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejos are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qNVYQZ

Comment: actually i solved the highlights already. if the user will erase the highlights it won't create a background or append a background white, it will move out from the span element with classname hlt. See the image above. That's not i am looking for. thanks @NagaSaiA i appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result , follow below option

1.Get selected text from button-Toggle using id- toggle
2.Add close tag before selection element and span tag with class -'hlt' using substring

HTML:

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cursus laoreet tincidunt vel, at purus sagittis ultrices <span class="hlt">varius elit accumsan, sed nulla aenean amet, nulla ac et, imperdiet </span>fermentum nulla ipsum risus leo.
</p>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $('span.hlt').removeClass('hlt');

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var text = selection.toString();
    var parent = $(selection.focusNode.parentElement);
    var oldHtml = parent.html();
    var position = oldHtml.indexOf(text);
    var end =(position*1)+selection.length
    console.log(text.length);
    var output = "<span class='hlt'>" +oldHtml.substr(0, position) + "</span>"+text+"<span class='hlt'>" + oldHtml.substr(position+text.length)+ "</span>";

    //var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(text, "</span>" + text + "<span class='hlt'>");
    parent.html(output);

  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.hlt{
  background:yellow;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dXkZwP

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejos,Hope this post with codepen works for you :)

Comment: thank u very much Naga Sai A. This code really help me. :)

Comment: Thanks @RoqueRemedioMejos, if my post help your question, please vote for me :)

Comment: i have a little problem on this it will highlight everything sometimes. i need to implement it to mouseup event. No worry about that but sometime i can highlight the whole text

Comment: there is something wrong with this code because it is possible to erase more than once, we cannot remove all the span classname hlt everytime the user erase it. Can u help this @nagaSaiA?

Comment: also when i include the non highlighted text the content will destroy hehe.. but thanks nagasai i really appreciate ur idea. great help to me also.

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejos checking code and update codepen soon

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejos check updated codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dXkZwP..Hope this works for you :)

Comment: thanks @nagaSaiA there is also same bug the updated codepen that u have given. Anyways ur idea really great help. thanks buddy..

Comment: Thanks @RoqueRemedioMejos

Comment: yes actually nagasai. when i erase over the limit of the highlighted text it won't work. for example the highlighted text is "Lorem". then i highlight it until "ipsum" then the highlight in Lorem wont erase.

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejosm, i couldn't replicate this issue

Comment: So no issues now ?

Comment: there is actually im trying to fix it out.