# JavaScript / jQuery getSelection Highlight merging the span html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```js
function highlight_text(sel) {
  span = htmlSpanHlt();
  if (sel.getRangeAt) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  }
  span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
  range.insertNode(span);
}

function htmlSpanHlt() {
  element = document.createElement("span");
  element.setAttribute('class', 'hlt');
  return element;
}
```

```css
.hlt {
 background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
  <p>
    <span class="hlt">Lorem</span> ipsum dolor sit amet, zril accusata postulant at ius. Dicat etiam luptatum ea pri. Duo docendi vulputate dissentiet ut, tollit bonorum duo eu. Maiorum adolescens scriptorem usu eu, sit idque facer causae ei. Choro nostrum at pro, sumo essent suscipiantur pri ex. Quo case veritus definiebas eu, sit postulant dissentias ei.<br>
    <br>
    Mel cu porro decore, cum et simul recteque inciderint. His ne omnes sententiae, ut omittantur dissentiet accommodare sed. Pro minim necessitatibus ne, no malis integre quo. Sed utroque molestiae interpretaris ne. Oportere indoctum at has, te sale semper eum, ea nam vitae dissentiet.
  </p>
</div>
```

The word "Lorem" has a classname "hlt" which was already been highlighted. What I want is: if I want to highlight another text including the word "Lorem" w/c is already been highlighted. I want to merge their span html element. Example: If I highlight "ipsum" next to the word "Lorem" and I include also "Lorem" the result will be Lorem Ipsum. Can someone help me? Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
function highlight_text(sel) {
   var hlt_element = document.getElementsByClassName('hlt')[0];
   if (!hlt_element || sel.containsNode(hlt_element,true)) {
      add_hlt_element(sel);
   }
}

function add_hlt_element(sel) {
   var element = document.createElement("span");
   var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
   element.setAttribute('class', 'hlt');
   element.innerHTML = sel.toString().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />\n');
   range.deleteContents();
   range.insertNode(element); 
   var highlight_div = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight")[0];
   highlight_div.innerHTML = highlight_div.innerHTML.replace('</span><span class="hlt">','');
}

window.onmouseup = function() {
   var sel = window.getSelection();
   highlight_text(sel);
}
```

```css
.hlt {
    background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, zril accusata postulant at ius. Dicat etiam luptatum ea pri. Duo docendi vulputate dissentiet ut, tollit bonorum duo eu. Maiorum adolescens scriptorem usu eu, sit idque facer causae ei. Choro nostrum at pro, sumo essent suscipiantur pri ex. Quo case veritus definiebas eu, sit postulant dissentias ei.<br>
    <br>
    Mel cu porro decore, cum et simul recteque inciderint. His ne omnes sententiae, ut omittantur dissentiet accommodare sed. Pro minim necessitatibus ne, no malis integre quo. Sed utroque molestiae interpretaris ne. Oportere indoctum at has, te sale semper eum, ea nam vitae dissentiet.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank u. but nothing will happen. and i can't highlight any text. and also the user can continue highlight and the override highlight their span will be merge.

Comment: ahh yeah it works actually. but that is only an example.the starting of the page there will be no highlight(s) should be, lorem is only an example after the user highlighted the text. if i highlighted lorem or any text then it will be highlighted. and if i override and expand my highlight the span will merge. your first answer that is right but it can only highlight one word.

Comment: and also it won't work if i started highlighting in the second letter and so on,,

Comment: your code is great. there is only two things missed. first: the user can start override the 2nd or 3rd letter and so on. and next the user can highlight the unhighlighted text and it will create a new span

Comment: yeah great. but i there is something with html structure. first it will not merge the span. example first i highlighted the "Lorem ipsum" the result will be <span class="hlt">Lorem ipsum</span> and that is correct. Then if I highlight again and override until the word "dolor sit" the result should be <span class="hlt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span>. it should not be span.hlt inside the span.hlt. u have really great logic

Comment: the reason why that is the structure because after that i will put it into single array and save into database.

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejos Ah, got it. I've edited code so that the `<span>` tags are all merged into one.

Comment: wow very impressive. but when u double click the text it ruin the newline. is that possible to fix that one?

Comment: can u help me to fix the breakline if it is okay? when i double click the text the breakline ruin. thanks @diglemister

Comment: @RoqueRemedioMejos Yes, I think that is happening because `range.toString()` ignores `<br>` tags. I edited to change to `sel.toString()`. That should work.

Comment: @digleMister can u help me to solve this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343030/erase-the-highlight-javascript-getselection-function

Comment: can i ask u to solve this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343030/erase-the-highlight-javascript-getselection-function ?